# check state is not empty then rerender failed in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
render(){
    const { user } = this.state;
    return(
      {user &&
      <Card className="container">
        <CardTitle
          title="User profile"
        />
        <li>Name: {user.name}</li>
      </Card>
      }
    )
  }
```

Why I can't do this? I have babel installed but above code throw me error at the `&&`, I have to check user exist because I call the API on componentDidMount, else user.name will got undefined error, but what's wrong with above code?

Answer (score 2):

`{...}` is used within JSX sections to insert a JavaScript expression. Where you're using it, you're not in a JSX section, so you don't need it. Just remove the `{` and `}` around that:

```
render() {
    const { user } = this.state;
    return (
        user &&                           // *** No `{`
        <Card className="container">
            <CardTitle
              title="User profile"
            />
            <li>Name: {user.name}</li>
        </Card>
    );                                    // *** No `}`
}
```

For that to work, it's imporrtant that `this.state.user` either be `null` (specifically) or a reference to an object; `undefined` won't cut it, `render` has to return `null` or a component.

Example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    let counter = 0;
    super(...args);
    this.state = {user: null};
    let timer = setInterval(_ => {
      this.setState(s => ({
        user: s.user ? null : {name: "Fred"}
      }));
      if (++counter === 7) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 800);
  }
  render() {
    const { user } = this.state;
    return (
      user &&
      <div>Name: {user.name}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
```